# Running .NET dll from coldfusion

Tags: .net, dll, coldfusion

I've done many searches and have done the suggestions that I've found, but nothing seems to be working. The most simple C# DLL file that returns a number:

```
namespace TestClass
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public int tester()
        {
            return 5;
        }
    }
}
```

the coldfusion code:

```
<cfobject type=".NET" name="myDLL" class="TestClass.Class1" assembly="d:/path/to/dll/TestClass.dll">
```

All of my attempts have lead me to this error:

```
Class TestClass.Class12 not found in the specified assembly list. 
The assembly that contains the class must be provided to the assembly attribute.
```

I have no clue where the problem could be. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, the code below does work:

```
<cfobject type=".NET" name="seClass" class="System.Environment">
<cfoutput>#seClass.Get_Version().ToString()#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Is the .NET integration service successfully installed and running as a service?

Comment: Re: *Class TestClass.Class12 not found*  - The class name is different than in code snippet ie `Class1` versus `Class12`. Is that just a typo? Fwiw, it worked perfectly for me right out of the gate. How did you create and compile your test class?

Comment: Also, check the assembly name in your VS project and make sure it is corret ie "TestClass"

Comment: @Leigh: yea, that was a typo...I'm just doing a build in VS CTRL+SHIFT+B and copying the DLL from the Bin\Release directory to the server.

Comment: Check your project settings. Are the `assemblyName` and `defaultNamespace` values both "TestClass"?

Comment: yea, both are set to TestClass...output type: class library using .NET Framework 4

Comment: Hmm.. I am grasping at straws now but does your version of CF support .net 4? Also if you have not already, I would restart the CF .NET service just to eliminate caching/file in use problems as possible causes. Other than that I am not sure what to suggest as it fine for me .net3.5/VS2005/CF10.

Comment: I think you need to be running CF9.0.1 for .NET 4 support.

Comment: I'll try to compile it at 3.5 tomorrow. But I know the server is CF9.0.1. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be some tricky trial and error to get this right. But the error is referring to an assembly list that is probably a part of the JNBDOtNetSide.exe.config file which can be found in the jnbridge directory (the path to this directory varies depending on how you set up your server).

Within the file you will find a commented out xml node under `<jnibridge>` that looks like this.

```
   <!--
    <assemblyList>
        <assembly file="path to first .NET-side assembly"/>
        <assembly file="path to second .NET-side assembly"/>
    </assemblyList>
    -->
```

You can try putting your path there and restarting the service. Other things to try - adding your assembly to the global cache and (last resort) deleting the core proxy jar file that is instnatiated in Web-INF. If you search my blog (coldfusionmuse.com) for ".NET Integration" you will find some additional clues that might get you started. Lot's of trial and error here though in my experience.

Comment: Unfortunately, I dont have access to any of that.

Comment: skeasor - running a .NET assembly without access to the services or GAC or config files may be a non-starter. If this is a shared environment the .NET service is often disabled and you *should* get a security warning.

Comment: I had our server guy take a look at everything and he said it "should" be okay. I'll play around with it a little more tomorrow.