# .net in Coldfusion (8) - "Class My.CSharp.Class not found in the specified assembly list."

Tags: c#, .net, coldfusion

I have created a class library (dll) and I want to use this in Coldfusion. The library works great when running it from a test console app, but when I try to load it into Coldfusion I get the error "Integration.Microsoft.Exchange.Email not found in the specified assembly list.". I'm very new to C# so I'm assuming I have done something wrong, but I'm lost as to what it is.

Coldfusion code:

```
<cfobject 
    action      =   "create"
    type        =   ".net" 
    name        =   "DotNetObject" 
    class       =   "Integration.Microsoft.Exchange.Email"
    assembly    =   "path\to\my\folder\Integration.Microsoft.Exchange.dll"
>
```

C# Code Structure:

```
namespace Integration.Microsoft.Exchange
{
    public class Email
    {
        public static void New ()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried a different dll (still specified through the assembly attribute) and it works fine. Is there something wrong with the way I've built my class?

The actual two C# class files are available here: http://www.seedata.co.uk/samples/csharp-exchange-integration/Classes.zip

Thanks!

Comment: _"Note: The names are changed, I'm not trying to call my class class"_ - then don't call it that here! If your actual name is so secret it can't be made public (doubtful), just call it "bob" or "foo" or <anything that isn't a language keyword or otherwise confusing name>.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147728/running-net-dll-from-coldfusion

Comment: Thanks for the helpful and relevant advice. I have updated my post. I have also read through your suggested article and it is not the same issue unfortunately - for clarity I have already tried all of those suggestions with no benefit. The key difference is that I can call in other .net classes so there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else that has issues with CF and .net, the solution to my problem in the end was very simple.

1. I was not paying attention to the target .net version when compiling in Visual Studio (obvious I know but had only been coding C# for a few hours when I did this)
2. Although I had the relevant .net version installed on my machine, the server had a version of .net that was not compatible with the libraries I was using

So a simple upgrade from .net 3.0 to 3.5 on the development server (you can't use anything higher than 3.5 on CF8) and changing my Visual Studio project to also compile to 3.5 solved the problem.

For anyone battling with this and thinking of giving up, the functionality is really quite good once you get it working!

Comment: Also just in case anyone still comes across this, remember that when you refer to the class parameter in cfobject, include the namespace before your class name.